# Automated form filling for beta testing web page forms

Tags: asp-classic, webforms, validation, beta, beta-testing

Does anyone know of an application that I could use for Beta testing web page forms. I am looking for something that I could click a button and it will populate all the data fields with generic information. The purpose is to test a website I build to see if any errors occur by running the application and having it just fill in random information in page form with different info, symbols and characters.

Comment: Why aren't you looking at using jQuery or Javascript for something like this?

Comment: From where?what? Give more information. Will the data be populated from DB of from the client side? Will the validation be from client of from server side?

Comment: Hello Fellas, I am just looking for something that could help me beta test a site I build that has forms on it. I wanted to see if there is an application that could pre-populate fields like name, address, city etc... and have it populate with all kinds of different information to see if any errors occur when I try to submit the page. Do you know anything? Thanks!!

Comment: please do not add signatures to your posts. [faq#signatures] Also, I don't think this would be specific to ASP -- form filling is a client side activity the way you're describing it, so any number of browser plugins should work.

Answer (score -1):

You can populate the form fields using this method...

First set some values, for example...

```
strFirstname = "Jeff"       'temporary fill
strLastname = "Black"
```

Then add the value to your form field...

```
<input type="text" name="Firstname" value="<%= strFirstname">">
<input type="text" name="Lastname" value="<%= strLastname">">
```

Now you only need to click your submit button.

When you are ready to go live, simply uncomment the temporary fill values. Then they are always there for future debugging by uncommenting them.

To see at a glance the results on the next page I use something like:

```
response.write("Firstname = " & request("Firstname") & "<BR>"
```

Comment: I am looking for software that could do it for me. For example QA Wizard Pro allows you to automate a load testing but creating scripts that will run functions on a site like if you wanted to load test 100 customers ordering products from a cart to see what would happen: http://www.seapine.com/qawizard.html Well I am looking for software that I could click a button and it fills in what ever webpage form are there automaticlly so I can see with just different values over all what would happen to the cart. Would it process or error. I can do it manually but...

Comment: It just takes to much time. I am going to be launching the site live and need to beta test for reliability and functionality. I will be using the load test from QA to test how it will handle with 100 people entering and submitting data to see how it handles that but would like to test the form validation with some kind of software as well. Know of anything that could do this?

Comment: I am creating new forms almost every week, some quite complex with conditional requirements such online purchasing orders and shopping cart lists, and the method that I described above is the only one that I trust. Although there is more too it... by response.writing the results on the new page I can see at a glance what worked and what didn't.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery, which is a Javascript add-on (client side).

If you want to target all input fields, you can do something like this...

```
$("form input").val(this.attr("name"));
```

Running this jQuery code would populate all the input fields with the value in the `Name` attribute.

So the `address` field would populate as `address`, but you can change the `this.attr("name")` to anything else and it will populate all the fields accordingly.

Not sure if this helps, but I would think this is the fastest way to populate all the input fields.  Take a look at jQuery http://www.jquery.com , I'm sure you'll find it helpful in your future in application development.